# Want to show border if selected - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, theming

I wanted to implement theming in my flutter app - I got to the point where I can successfully change themes and the dialog to change them pops up as expected... now I want to show the user which theme is selected so I wanted to have a border that goes around the selected theme as in the screenshot

[image: themepicker]

Thats the code I used so far for picking the theme and for displaying the themepickercontainers

```
    class MultiThemeModel {
      int index;
      String themeName;
      Color color;
      bool selected;
    
      MultiThemeModel(
          {required this.index,
          required this.themeName,
          required this.color,
          required this.selected});
    }
    
    titlesForThemeModel(int index) {
      switch (index) {
        case 0:
          return 'Luxury Purple';
        case 1:
          return 'Red Wine';
      }
      return 'No theme for index';
    }
    
    colorsForThemeModel(int index) {
      switch (index) {
        case 0:
          return purpleBackgroundColor;
        case 1:
          return redBackgroundColor;
      }
    }
    
    selectedForThemeModel(int index) {
      switch (index) {
        case 0:
          return true;
        case 1:
          return false;
      }
    }
    
    List<MultiThemeModel> get themes => List<MultiThemeModel>.generate(
        2,
        (index) => MultiThemeModel(
            index: index,
            themeName: titlesForThemeModel(index),
            color: colorsForThemeModel(index),
            selected: selectedForThemeModel(index)));
    
    List<Widget> get widgets => themes
        .map((themeData) => MultipleThemeViewerWidget(themeData: themeData))
        .toList();
    
    class MultipleThemeViewerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MultipleThemeViewerWidget({Key? key, required this.themeData})
      : super(key: key);
  final MultiThemeModel themeData;

  @override
  State<MultipleThemeViewerWidget> createState() =>
      _MultipleThemeViewerWidgetState();
}

class _MultipleThemeViewerWidgetState extends State<MultipleThemeViewerWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        getThemeManager(context).selectThemeAtIndex(widget.themeData.index);
        setState(() {
          // selectedForThemeModel(widget.themeData.index) =
          widget.themeData.selected = !widget.themeData.selected;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 60,
        width: 105,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: widget.themeData.color.withOpacity(.3),
            border: widget.themeData.selected
                ? Border.all(color: widget.themeData.color, width: 3)
                : Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            widget.themeData.themeName,
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              textStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: widget.themeData.color,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

now as far as I can imagine that it should work if id be able to change the return statement of selectedForThemeModel in the onTap function of the MultipleThemeViewerWidget... my problem is that I don't know whether that is even possible and if so how it would be implemented in the onTap function

thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a little rebuilding, try converting to stateful widget and try the below

```
 return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        getThemeManager(context).selectThemeAtIndex(themeData.index);

        setState(() {});
      },
```

**EDIT**
A little refreshing was exactly what we needed but setState wasn't the answer.

With the use of ValueNotifier, we can update the state immediately we change it.

Here are the changes

```dart
class MultiThemeModel {
  int index;
  String themeName;
  Color color;
  ValueNotifier<bool> selected;

  MultiThemeModel(
      {required this.index,
      required this.themeName,
      required this.color,
      required this.selected});
}

selectedForThemeModel(int index) {
  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      return ValueNotifier(true);
    case 1:
      return ValueNotifier(false);
  }
}

class MultipleThemeViewerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MultipleThemeViewerWidget(
      {Key? key, required this.themeData, required this.themes})
      : super(key: key);
  MultiThemeModel themeData;
  List<MultiThemeModel> themes;
  @override
  State<MultipleThemeViewerWidget> createState() =>
      _MultipleThemeViewerWidgetState();
}

class _MultipleThemeViewerWidgetState extends State<MultipleThemeViewerWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: widget.themeData.selected,
        builder: (context, bool selected, _) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              getThemeManager(context)
                  .selectThemeAtIndex(widget.themeData.index);
              if (!selected) {
                widget.themeData.selected.value = true;
                widget.themes
                    .elementAt(widget.themeData.index == 0 ? 1 : 0)
                    .selected
                    .value = false;
              }
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 60,
              width: 105,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: widget.themeData.color.withOpacity(.3),
                  border: selected
                      ? Border.all(color: widget.themeData.color, width: 3)
                      : Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  widget.themeData.themeName,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: widget.themeData.color,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.themeData.selected.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: actually changing the theme isnt the problem... my problem is that I want to set a boolean to true/false depending on which theme is chosen... so if the purple theme is chosen the purple burder is shown and if the red one is chosen the red one is shown you know... I thought about converting the widget to a stateful widget and using setstate to set the boolean for the cases but I don't know how to access and change the values in the cases...

Comment: so what I mean by that is if I manually change the return value for the cases of selectedForThemModel the border is shown but I don't know whether that is even possible with something like setstate... what I would like to do is ontap change both values to the opposite so for example if I tap on red I want case 0 to return false and case 1 to return true and so on but I'm not sure how to implement this

Comment: By manually do you mean from your code? Try this, click on your ontap, then hot reload your app if the border stuff changes then you have more idea on what to do. Why i said you should attempt calling setState is because due to my experience, the value can/will change but won't reflect on the screen.

Comment: You should be able to change the value of `themeData.selected` by use `themeData.selected = whatever`.

Comment: So if I change the return value manually in my code the dialog is refreshed on reload but I don't know how I can reference the value with setstate... if I try to use setstate selectedForThemeModel(widget.themeData.index) = false I get an error....

Comment: i updated the code above accordingly but It still doesn't refresh even after reloading... I tried to use a local variable but then I get the problem, that the border of the other container is still shown even if the other container is chosen... that's why I wanted to find a way to change the return value of the selectedForThemeMOdel or sth but I'm not sure how...

Comment: Can you show the code that contains the whole popup? I belief this code is for each color.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242700/discussion-between-frank-nike-and-jonas-jacob-biermann).

Comment: @JonasJacobBiermann Wonder if this will eventually get up voted.